# Why fgets is reading the input, even though there is EOF in the input string?

Tags: c, fgets

I read the `man` page of `fgets()`. It states "Reading stops after an EOF or a newline". My code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define MAX 50 
int main() 
{ 
    char buf[MAX]; 
    fgets(buf, MAX, stdin); 
    printf("string is: %s\n", buf); 

    return 0; 
}
```

I gave this input :Welcome to -1 kkWorld.
Output is: string is: Welcome to -1 kkWorld
`fgets` should stop reading when it sees -1 in the input. Why is fgets reading even though there is -1 or EOF in the string?  Am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: The sub-string, "-1" is just two characters, `-` and `1`. Neither of these is `EOF`.

Comment: To put an EOF char in the file, you need to put \0x00 hex char in the file

Comment: @R.LM: I don't think that's true. The point of `EOF` is that it is different from any possible (unsigned) character value. It's just a special value that signals the end of the file in some input functions like `fgetc` (but not in `fgets`, which is used here). The `EOF` is not in the file.

Comment: @MOehm Please see the `man` page of `fgets`.  It states "Reading stops after an EOF or a newline".

Comment: Yes, but `EOF` is not a character, it is the end of the file or an error condition.

Comment: @R.LM  I gave input as: `Welcome to kk\0x00 World`.  Output is `string is: Welcome to kk\0x00 World`.

Comment: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ is good reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Adrian, inputing "-1" ends up being two characters; '-' and '1'.  To emulate an EOF character, you must enter the single EOF value constant.

EOF can be input to the program with **Ctrl-D** (Unix/Linux), or **CTRL-Z** (Microsoft).

Comment: How do I input `CTRL+D` to a program? Please tell us

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula: Your program reads from `stdin`. If your redirected input from a file, `EOF` wil be signalled by the end of the redirected input. If you type in the input interactively from the terminal, you can use these special keys (usually after a new-line) to terminate input and to signal `EOF` to the program.